# Reverse row and column transformation within Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe where I would like to maintain all columns in my original dataset and create a new pivoted column based on existing dataset.

**Data**

```
 stat1 stat2    id  q122con q122av  q122con q122av  q222con q222av  q222con q222av
 50    1000     aa  40      10      900     100     50      0       1000    0   
 100   2000     bb  50      50      1500    500     75      25      1900    100
```

**Desired**

```
stat1   stat2   id  date    con         av          con         av      
50      1000    aa  q122    40          10          900         100             
50      1000    aa  q222    50          0           1000        0               
100     2000    bb  q122    50          50          1500        500             
100     2000    bb  q222    75          25          1900        100
```

**Doing**

```
df.pivot(index="id", columns="date", values=["con", "av"])
```

However, I am not obtaining the full columns within my dataset.
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Look into `pd.wide_to_long`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some long one line by `wide_to_long`

```
pd.wide_to_long(df.set_index(['stat1','stat2','id']).stack().groupby(level=[0,1,2,3]).agg(list).apply(pd.Series).unstack().stack(level=0).reset_index(),
                stubnames = ['q122','q222'], i = ['stat1','stat2','id','level_3'],j = 'date',suffix='\\w+').stack().unstack(level=[-3,-2])
Out[140]: 
level_3               0        1      
date                 av con   av   con
stat1 stat2 id                        
50    1000  aa q122  10  40  100   900
               q222   0  50    0  1000
100   2000  bb q122  50  50  500  1500
               q222  25  75  100  1900
```

Comment: hi @BENY also what does the .stack().unstack(level=[-3,-2]) refer to? is this then removing certain columns?  Also what is the groupby(level=[0,1,2,3])? is this signifying the # of columns? (av, con, av con?) thanks

Comment: I am not getting desired result using the above script. I will continue to research

Answer (score 2):

Lot of your issues here is dealing with duplicate column names:

```
import pandas as pd

# Duplicating input dataframe with clipboard and remove dot numbers assign for duplicate column headers
df = pd.read_clipboard()
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('.').str[0]


# Set index to move first three columns into index
df = df.set_index(['stat1','stat2','id'])

# Use groupby and cumcount to get order of duplicate column headers
cols = df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).cumcount().rename('No').reset_index()

# Use str.extract to split "dates" from av and con with regex
cols = cols['index'].str.extract('(q\d{3})(.*)').join(cols).drop('index', axis=1)

# Create a new multiIndex column header
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(cols, names=['date','av','con'])

# Reshape dataframe by stacking the outer most column header to the dataframe index
# And moved those columns from the index back into the dataframe with reset_index
df_out =  df.stack(0).reset_index()

# Flatten headers back to one level
df_out.columns = [f'{i}_{j}' if j else f'{i}' for i, j in df_out.columns]

# And print
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
   stat1  stat2  id  date  av  av_1  con  con_1
0     50   1000  aa  q122  10   100   40    900
1     50   1000  aa  q222   0     0   50   1000
2    100   2000  bb  q122  50   500   50   1500
3    100   2000  bb  q222  25   100   75   1900
```

Comment: I am getting value error with the second line of code: ValueError: Length of passed values is 8, index implies 2. @Scott Boston - I will research

Answer (score 1):

It's not as pretty as the other solutions but it works:

```
out = df.set_index(['stat1','stat2','id']).stack()
idx = pd.DataFrame(out.index.tolist())
count = idx.groupby(idx.columns.tolist()).cumcount().tolist()
idx = (idx.iloc[:,:-1]
       .merge(idx.iloc[:,-1].str.extract('(q\d{3})(.*)'), left_index=True, right_index=True))
out.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(idx, names=['stat1','stat2','id','date','val'])
out = (out
       .to_frame()
       .assign(count=count)
       .groupby(['count','val','stat1','stat2','id','date'])
       .first()
       .unstack(level=[0,1])
       .droplevel([0,1], axis=1)
       .reset_index()
      )
print(out)
```

Output:

```
val  stat1  stat2  id  date  av  con   av   con
0       50   1000  aa  q122  10   40  100   900
1       50   1000  aa  q222   0   50    0  1000
2      100   2000  bb  q122  50   50  500  1500
3      100   2000  bb  q222  25   75  100  1900
```

Figured out a simpler way. Moreover, the above produces duplicate columns:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()
out = df.set_index(['stat1', 'stat2', 'id'])
out.columns = out.columns.str.split("((av)|(con))", expand = True).droplevel([-2,-3])
out = out.stack(level=0)
out.columns = [''.join(col) for col in out.columns]
out = out.reset_index().rename(columns={'level_3':'date'})
```

Output:

```
  stat1 stat2   id  date    av  av.1    con con.1
0   50  1000    aa  q122    10  100 40  900
1   50  1000    aa  q222    0   0   50  1000
2   100 2000    bb  q122    50  500 50  1500
3   100 2000    bb  q222    25  100 75  1900
```